# Exception if object doesn't exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my application I get the id from the route/URL. What should I do in my controller if there is no object with this id?

My favorite solution would be to throw a 404. Is this a good idea? Are there any helpers for this common problem?

```
// url /groups/1

public function group($group_id)
{
    if (! Group::find($group_id)) {
        App::abort(404);
    }
 }
```

In Django there is a short cut function for this problem. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Eloquent::findOrFail($pk)`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) is what you are looking for.  This will throw a `ModelNotFoundException`.  Here's how I would set this up:

**Controller**

```
public function group($group_id)
{
    // This will throw an App::error() when $group_id doesn't exist
    $group = Group::findOrFail($group_id);
}
```

**Routes** (or something similar)

```
App::error(function(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    // This will be ran when ::findOrFail() doesn't find an object
    App::abort(404);
});
```